# How do i move data from One Database to another on SQL using SSIS

Tags: sql, database, ssis

I am trying to load data from a database on SQL to my Database and i can see that the data has moved but the data is not loaded on my Database.

This is my output message

> Information: 0x4004300C at SALES ETL, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is
> beginning. Information: 0x402090DF at SALES ETL, OLE DB Destination
> [117]: The final commit for the data insertion in "OLE DB Destination"
> has started. Information: 0x402090E0 at SALES ETL, OLE DB Destination
> [117]: The final commit for the data insertion  in "OLE DB
> Destination" has ended. Information: 0x40043008 at SALES ETL,
> SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning. Information:
> 0x4004300B at SALES ETL, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote
> 1915 rows. Information: 0x40043009 at SALES ETL, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Cleanup phase is beginning. SSIS package \Package.dtsx" finished:
> Success.

i have tried debugging with every step.

what else can i do to ensure the data is showing on my database?

i have tried debugging with by changing the lookup values and its is still same output.

Comment: Hi - as the data is being shown as having moved then either you don’t have the necessary permissions to see the  data in the target DB or it’s not being written to the DB you think it is (or possibly there’s a refresh issue with the client app you are using to query the target)

Comment: It thinks it wrote 1,915 rows somewhere. Maybe you're in the wrong database. Are the two databases on the same server? There's an easier way to do this.